# Remote upload using WLST

Tags: deployment, weblogic, war, ear, wlst

I'm trying to perform **remote uploading and deploying via WLST**.
I succeed to deploy applications already present in the path of the WebLogic server. But now, I would like to deploy one remotely available.

Is there **any possibility to upload WAR/EAR on the WebLogic server via WLST** before deploying it?

I'm running weblogic 12C.

I tried with:

```
java -cp wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.Deployer -adminurl t3://WeblogicServer:7001 -user weblogic -password weblogic -deploy /tmp/HelloWorld.war -remote -upload
```

give me as return:

```
weblogic.Deployer invoked with options:  -adminurl t3://WeblogicServer:7001 -user weblogic -deploy /tmp/HelloWorld.war -remote -upload
<6 juil. 2012 17 h 58 CEST> <Info> <J2EE Deployment SPI> <BEA-260121> <Initiating deploy operation for application, HelloWorld [archive: /tmp/HelloWorld.war], to configured targets.> 
[J2EE Deployment SPI:260080]Unable to define the application install directory at "/tmp/helloworld.war". Directory could not be created or is a file.
```

And when i check on the server, nothing is deployed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:
**We must not use the /tmp directory as source**, because the weblogic.Deployer use this directory.

So the command is:

```
java -cp wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.Deployer -adminurl
 t3://WeblogicServer:7001 -user weblogic -password weblogic -deploy 
/home/admin/HelloWorld.war -remote -upload
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. Take a look at [WLST `deploy` command reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/config_scripting/reference.html#wp1024285) (This link is for version 10gR3).
You can specify the `remote` and the `upload` options with `true`, since their default values are false.

PS 1: The `remote` option is not available on WebLogic 9.0 and older versions (but you can always get a newer `weblogic.jar` and try.
PS 2: You will need to have remote access to the administrative interfaces (usually ports 7001 and/or 7002). That means opening firewalls, etc.
PS 3: Please provide the version of your WebLogic server, as this might help us help you.

Comment: Never seen such error. Will take a look and let you know if I find something.

Comment: I got [J2EE Deployment SPI:260080]Unable to define the application install directory at "/tmp/helloworld.war". Directory could not be created or is a file.

Comment: A couple of things you might try: First: please add `-source` before your .war path (`... -deploy -source /tmp/HelloWorld.war` ...). Second: take a look into your server's `/tmp` folder and look for a `helloworld.war` file. If it exists, delete it and try again. Third: add something like `-Djava.io.tmpdir=${WL_DOMAIN_HOME}/tmp` to your managed and admin startup scripts. It might be possible that your WL is using `/tmp/filename` as default. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I tried ur recommendations, but nothing changes.. However running the command with debug mode gave me something interesting about the App root and App config. Look on : http://pastebin.com/G0ra5khx  . But i don't know yet what's the meanning of these variables.

Comment: And : https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=834572.. but nothing new

Comment: Those values look ok, I don't think they are related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Written myself, can do undeploy + deploy. The deploy line is:

> deploy( project, archive
>           , apptargets, 'stage', plan
>           , remote='true', upload='true', archiveVersion=archiveversion, planVersion=planversion )

- disadvantage of using version number in deploy is that redeploy with plan is not working

Complete script: (line next code out yourself, I had to add some spaces to place it here)

```
from java.io import FileReader
from datetime import datetime


def deployApp( project, archive, archiveversion, plan, planversion, apptargets ):

#### UNDEPLOY app          
try:

    domainConfig()
    cd('/')
    found = false
    for app in cmo.getAppDeployments():
        name=app.getName()

        try:                 
            cd('/AppDeployments/' + name ) 
            applicationName=get('ApplicationName')

            if applicationName==project:
                print '\n__ FOUND aplication: ', name
                found = true

                version=get('VersionIdentifier')
                sourcePath=get('SourcePath')
                planPath=get('PlanPath')

                targets=''
                for target in cmo.getTargets():

                    targetName=target.getName()
                    if targets=='':
                        targets=targetName
                    else:
                        targets=targets + ', ' + targetName

                print '   applicationName:\t', applicationName
                print '   version:\t\t', version
                print '   sourcePath:\t', sourcePath
                print '   planPath:\t', planPath
                print '   targets:\t\t', targets

                if version==archiveversion + '#' + planversion: 
                    print '\nCorrect Application version found.  No installation needed\n'
                    return
                else:
                    print '\n__ REMOVING application: ',applicationName, '     version:', version 
                    undeploy(project)

        except:     
            print "IGNORE ERROR: (deployed applicaties gegevens ophalen) ", sys.exc_info()[0]

    if found==false:
        print "Application " + project + "not found."

except:     
    print "Failure in application remove part: ", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise   


# get deploy targets
try:   
    if apptargets==None:
        serverConfig()
        cd('/')
        targetList = []              
        for cluster in cmo.getClusters():
            targetList.append( cluster.getName() )
        apptargets = ",".join(targetList)

        print 'USING default app target:', apptargets, "   (apptargets not found in environmentfile)" 
except:
    print "Failure while creating default target", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise 


#### DEPLOY app
try:         
    print '\n__ DEPLOYING application: ', project, archiveversion + '#' + planversion  + '    target:' + apptargets

    deploy( project, archive
    , apptargets, 'stage', plan
    , remote='true', upload='true', archiveVersion=archiveversion, planVersion=planversion )
except:     
    print "Failure in deployment part: ", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise


# connect to domein
# 1) in plain passsword
# 1)  using encrypted domain credential in separate files
# 2)  using encrypted domain credential in home directory user
def Connect( domainproperties ):
plainUser = domainproperties.getProperty("user")
plainPassword = domainproperties.getProperty("password")
if not (plainUser is None) and not (plainPassword is None):
    print "Connecting with user & password"
    connect( plainUser, plainPassword, domainproperties.getProperty("url"))
    return        

encryptedUserConfigFile = domainproperties.getProperty("encryptedCredentialsFile")
encryptionKeyFile = domainproperties.getProperty("encryptionKeyFile")    
if not (encryptedUserConfigFile is None) and not (encryptionKeyFile is None):
    print "Connecting with encryptedCredentialsFile: ", encryptedUserConfigFile, "  and encryptionKeyFile: ", encryptionKeyFile 
    connect(userConfigFile=encryptedUserConfigFile, userKeyFile=encryptionKeyFile, url=domainproperties.getProperty("url"))
    return

print "Connecting with encryptedCredentialsFile in home directory"
connect( url=domainproperties.getProperty("url") )
return    



try:
print "____ running app_deploy.py at   " + str(datetime.now())

project = sys.argv[1]
archive = sys.argv[3]
archiveversion = sys.argv[4]
plan = sys.argv[5]
planversion = sys.argv[6]    
environmentfile = sys.argv[2]

propertyfilereader=FileReader(environmentfile)
domainproperties=Properties()
domainproperties.load(propertyfilereader)

print "  environment: ", environmentfile 
print "  Ear:   ", archive, "  version:", archiveversion
print "  plan:  ", plan, "  version:", planversion

## Connect
#connect( domainproperties.getProperty("user"), domainproperties.getProperty("password"), domainproperties.getProperty("url") )
Connect( domainproperties )

try: 

    ## Deploy
    deployApp( project, archive, archiveversion, plan, planversion, domainproperties.getProperty("apptargets") )

finally:
    # niet dat het uitmaakt, maar wel zo netjes
    disconnect()

except:
print "ABORT APP DEPLOY: ", #  sys.exc_info()[0], "_", sys.exc_info()[1]
raise
```

Have fun with it.