# upload a jar file in remote Weblogic server using wlst

Tags: weblogic, aspectj, wlst

Is there a way to upload a jar file to a specific location on remote weblogic server using wlst?
This is my scenario - 
I need to upload aspectjweaver.jar to the remote server. This needs to be done before weblogic startup, as weaving takes place during startup .
FTP is not an option because those ports are blocked.

Comment: You mean uploading but not deploying? Or do you want to deploy it to your server too?

Comment: did you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355642/remote-upload-using-wlst)